# Why does the "day" in "Name day" is lowercase while being uppercase in "Mother's Day"?

Tags: spelling

When you open the [Name day article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_day), you can see that the word *day* is not capitalised.

I thought this is a rule but then I've found [this page of Finnish Name Days](http://www.nordicnames.de/wiki/Finnish_Name_Days) where *days* start with a capital letter.

On the other hand, the *day* word starts with *D* both in [Father's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father%27s_Day) and [Mother's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother%27s_Day).

What's the rule here? Is it a mistake that *Name day* on Wikipedia is not capitalised?

Comment: In the article, it's *a name day* (or *name days*), not *Name day*. This should be similar to the spelling of *birthday*, i.e. we write *Tomorrow is my sister's birthday*, not *Tomorrow is my sister's Birthday*. The title of the page *Finnish Name Days* is different because it's a title.

Comment: @DamkerngT. : You should write your comment as an answer. That a good explanation.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'd be delighted to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I posted my answer. :-) Anyway, it's recommend on ELL to wait for a while (half a day or a day) to let other users see your questions, and possibly post their answers, which may add additional useful information or may take the question-answer from a different angle entirely.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ok, I'll remember about that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article, it's *a name day* (or *name days*), not *Name day*. This should be similar to the spelling of *birthday*, i.e. we write *Tomorrow is my sister's birthday*, not *Tomorrow is my sister's Birthday*.

The title of the page *Finnish Name Days* is different because it's a title. There are a number of title case styles in English. You can read more about title case on Wikipedia: [Letter case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case), under sections [Title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Stylistic_or_specialised_usage) and [Headings and publication titles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles).